# how to place buttons on a layout based on condition?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android layout in which I will place 3 buttons vertically with some space between them. But based on the requirements, the  button count can come down to 2, and I need the buttons to repositioned based on  the available screen space.See the screens below.

[image: 3 buttons]

now the second case with two buttons should be like

[image: 2 buttons]

How should I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set visibility of buttons depending upon your condition just like the following:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When you set visibility to gone then the space will considered available for other layouts and your will be set as per your desire.

When you set visibility to invisible then the space will considered as allocated.

Comment: @Backspace Is "Accept Answer" award possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for achieving the same based on your condition for adding buttons to your layout

```
//the layout on which you are working
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

//set the properties for button
Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btnTag.setText("Button");
btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

//add button to the layout
layout.addView(btnTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define all three buttons in the layout XML and then :

if you want to show the third button

```
 thirdButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

if you want to hide

```
 thirdButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

at least if using a Linear or Relative Layout it should repositione by itself.